# TaskList.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: todo.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am working with Reactjs and I can't resolve this problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function TaskList() {

    const [todo, setTodo] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const axiosMembers = async () => {
            const response = await axios
                .get('/todolist').then((res) => {
                    setTodo(res.data)
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        };
        axiosMembers();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    todo.map((obj) => {
                       <li>{obj.title}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's the return of your api call ?

Comment: Hi, console.log(res.data) give me this table  [{'id': 1, 'title': 'laravel', 'description': 'learn laravel'}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'REACT', 'description': 'learn react'}, {'id': 3, 'title': 'flask', 'description': 'learn flask'}]

Comment: but console.log(todo) give me nothing

Comment: @brahim. i have created sample test based on your code. it works  properly .https://codesandbox.io/s/small-shape-jzpsv?file=/src/App.js .  and https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-boyd-j1wci?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.